# Print call stack of recursive loop

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there a generic function (`printCallStack`) that will print the call stack of a recursive loop.

For example,

```
printCallStack(length ([7, 1 'quot' 0]))
```

prints call stack :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for something like [Hat](http://projects.haskell.org/hat/), which is a source level tracer for haskell, and possibly specifically for hat-stack, which is the stack tracer component.

You can alternatively use the debugger/tracer built into ghci. Not as nice as hat, but doesn't require to recompile your code and it's readily available. In case you wonder, it's the `:trace` command in ghci.

Comment: @mb14 Yes, in the past. However version 2.8.0.0 seems have problems to build cleanly on Windows due to an "unknown type name 'uint32_t" error message, in case this is the problem that you are seeing with it.